# Copy text from one line and create a new line with that next under it

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a text file in which I want to find all of ID:= "abc123" when it finds that I want it to take that value of abc123 and create a new line and have a set string, newId:= "abc123 How can I do this within terminal?

I'd like to use bash, below are some examples, find the string '"ID": ", copy the value (abc123) and make a new line with this data.

```
"ID": "abc123"
"newID": "abc123"
```

Comment: This is not clear if `ID` is part of the string or not. Make an effort to presentation.

Comment: Please specify what shell you use. bash? ksh? ...

Comment: See the contextual help when you edit your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sed -e 's/^"ID": "\(.*\)"/&\
"newID": "\1"/' myfile.txt
```

First, I'll try to explain the regular expression that searches for matches:

1. `^` Matches the start of the line
2. `"ID": "` Matches that exact string
3. `\(.*\)` Matches a sequence of zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`). Placing this expression between backslashed parenthesis creates a "capture", which allows us to store the resulting part of the match into an auxiliary variable `\1`.
4. `"` Matches the double-quote character

When it finds a match, it replaces it with:

1. `&` the match itself. This operator is an auxiliary variable that represents what was matched.
2. `\<new-line>` the backslash followed by an actual new line character escapes a new line, ie. it allows us to print a new line character into the replacement
3. `"newId": "` prints that exact string
4. `\1` prints the contents of our capture, so it prints the ID we found
5. `"` prints a double quote character.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: hmm just seems to be printing the entire text file and not adding the new line. Perhaps its an issue that the line with ID: actually starts with a few spaces?

Comment: It is. You can remove the first operator (the `^`) from the regex, and it will search for it anywhere on the line. A possibly better solution would be to add `[ \t]*` after the `^`, which then expects zero or more characters that are either spaces or tabs.

Comment: Thanks! - the only thing remaining is that it doesn't seem as though the new line is actually being created. its adding it to the same line.

Comment: That's weird, are you entering both lines as separate lines into the shell?

Comment: Sorry, changing it to an actual script vs a single terminal command worked.

Comment: Last question, since I'm making a new line I need to add a comma to end of the line which I'm copying the ID from. Possible?

Comment: Sure, you can add a literal `,` where you want it to be. I would guess you'd want it between the `&` and the backslashed newline. As long as you don't put it after a backslash (which could un-escape a characted intended to be escaped), you can place it anywhere in the replacement string =)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -r 's@^"ID": "([a-Z0-9]+)"@"newID": "\1"@' file.txt
```

- `sed` : the executable
- `-r` : extented mode (no need to backslash parenthesis)
- `s` : we perform a substitution, skeleton is `s@origin@replacement@` (the separator can be anything)
- `^` : means start of line in *regex*
- `( )` : parenthesis is a *capture*
- `"newID":` is the start of the new string
- `\1` : is the end of the substituted string (the captured string)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what this is doing?

Answer (score -1):

Considering your question is very vague I made some assumptions which will become apparent in my implementation.

INPUT FILE -- call it t

```
ID="one"
dkkd
ID="two"

ffkjf
ID="three"
ldl
```

Command ran on input file

```
for line in `cat t`; do newID=`echo $line | grep ID | cut -d= -f2`; if [[ "$newID" != "" ]]; then echo $line >> t2; echo newID=$newID >> t2; else echo $line >> t2; fi; done
```

OUTPUT FILE -- Name is t2 (apparent from the command)

```
ID="one"
newID="one"
dkkd
ID="two"
newID="two"
ffkjf
ID="three"
newID="three"
ldl
```

Basically this command goes line by line in the file (in this case called t) looks for an ID line. If it finds one it gets its value, prints the original line with the ID and then prints another one with a newID following right after. If the line in question does not have and ID then it just prints the line it self.

Things to note:

If you have any other line in the file that contains "ID" in it but is not the normal ID that you requested, this will not work.